# How to set Alarm using alarm clock class

Tags: android, clock, alarm

Hi I am trying to set Alarm in my application Using the AlarmClock class. I am using the code as follows:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
 startActivity(intent);
```

But I am getting an exception. Can anyone please tell how to use this new Android feature?

Answer (score 10):

You'll also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

to your manifest.

Answer (score 9):

Ollie is right, the code should look something like the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 9);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 37);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the time when the alarm is being set for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html

You're asking Android to set an alarm without telling it when, so add extra intent bundle parameters for Hour & Minutes and then I expect it will work (it is hard to be sure as you've provided no information about the exception).