# Android built in phone timer app (clock) usage in code

Tags: android, timer

I would like my app to use the built in timer app pre-installed on every phone, like the google app when I say "remind me in x minutes" and it activates the clock app timer, is it possible to use this in my app as well? did not find any info in the web,
thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989757/how-to-set-alarm-using-alarm-clock-class

Comment: This is an alarm clock, I would like to use the count down function of the clock app

Comment: The Alarm Clock has the ability to set a timer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SET_TIMER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Alarm Clock to create a timer using:

```
Intent setTimer = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER);
setTimer.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, 60);
setTimer.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "My Amazing timer");
setTimer.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, false);
startActivity(setTimer);
```

Make sure to add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```